# How to read and write to a stream at the same time

Tags: c#, stream

I have a stream that is being read by one thread, while writing data into the stream from another thread.

The problem is that the reading thread exits immediately because it thinks that there is no more data in the stream.

Comment: What is the stream representing?  A file?  If so, you're using the wrong tool for inter-process communication.  Use something like a named pipe which will allow you to generate streams that are specifically designed for these purposes.

Comment: @Servy The stream is an audio coming via http request.

Comment: Then that must be inter-thread communication, not inter-**process** communication.  There's a *world* of difference between the two.  A memory stream would only be accessible *within* a single process.

Comment: @Servy by "process" I meant a Thread

Comment: There's a *huge* difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `BlockingCollection` to represent a pipeline of information going from one thread to another.  The producing thread writes data, in this case bytes or a block of bytes, to the collection, while another thread reads that data.  The `BlockingCollection` class will take care of all of the needed synchronization.

You then have a separate function of being able to mark the collection as "completed" to indicate that no more information will be written.